# Why do I have to 'buy' a free item in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

When using the Ubuntu Software Center, why do I have to go through the extra steps to 'buy' a free item? Why can't it just get installed?

Comment: Please be specific.  What's your question?

Comment: This is a known bug of the software center, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/968974

Comment: It's a trap to get you to register with Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 6):

Some applications in the software center are commercial, but free, rather than open source.  For commercial apps the process has you click through "buy" even though it's free. Some developers do this to avoid the long wait for open source applications (mine has been languishing since the end of September for example)

Comment: I never thought about this. Where is this long wait coming from? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm not sure the delay, but I think it was lack of reviewers. I don't think the situation still applies with Touch apps.