# can any one recommend me free stock market software?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have tried to install qtstalker,grism. But it is not available in my ubuntu software center.I guess it is not available on ubuntu 14.04.

Can anyone recommend me free software for 'technical analysis' of stocks, which is available for ubuntu 14.04?

Can I make Tradestation,metacharts,ninjatrader work on ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

From the [source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuFinance):

**Stock Market monitoring software**

BeanCounter - A stock portfolio performance monitoring tool. Install:

```
sudo apt-get install beancounter
```

Smtm - Show Me The Money is a configurable Perl/Tk stock ticker program. Written by the creator of BeanCounter.

```
sudo apt-get install smtm
```

JStock -- a Java based portfolio manager and stock market monitoring tool. [See these installation instructions](http://jstock.sourceforge.net/help_install_upgrade.html#install-linux).

---

- qtstalker is available from 'precise'  http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/qtstalker
- I found a .DEB here: http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/ubuntu//pool/universe/q/qtstalker/qtstalker_0.32-3.3ubuntu1_i386.deb so might be worth a shot to try and install it in 13.04 (download it and double click the download and USC will take over).

Comment: For additional information, JStock works well too in Android platform : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yccheok.jstock.gui (Disclaim : I'm the author)

Answer (score 4):

[Chart Geany [image: Install chart-geany-trial]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chart-geany-trial) is a nice technical analysis software.

You can find it in the Software Center, or you can simply click the below button to install it:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Thanks for your time. I searched 'Chart Geany' in software center and found one. It's stated that 'free'. But instead of 'install' option there is 'buy' option.

Comment: This will answer your comment http://askubuntu.com/a/225903/71679

Answer (score 1):

There is a modern, command line tool written in GoLang (also available for macOS)

https://github.com/mop-tracker/mop

There seems no package available for Ubuntu, on GitHub are instructions how to build from source.

> Mop: track stocks the hacker way
>
> Mop is a command-line utility that displays continuous up-to-date
> information about the U.S. markets and individual stocks. One
> screenshot is worth a thousand words:

[image]