# trading and charting platform for ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-recommendation

is there any charting and trading platform available for ubuntu 15.10 64 bit which get data from yahoo/google EOD / RT and shows charts Pitch fork , p&F etc. for indian market ?

FYI: 
http://www.multicharts.com/ ; http://ninjatrader.com/ i used to know very popular trading platform but for windows only . is there anything same for ubuntu 15.10 64 bit ? i am looking for some alternatives to them in ubuntu 15.10 64 bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can any one recommend me free stock market software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/347008/can-any-one-recommend-me-free-stock-market-software)

Comment: no not convincing in charting.

Comment: "no not convincing in charting" I have no idea what that comment means? Are you not looking for stock tracking software? If not you really need to edit your question. The second answer is `chart geany` did you try that? Seems like it would be good at charting.]

Comment: stock/portfolio tracking and trading/charting platform are different . chart giny is not open source way bellow trading platform than TS or MultiCharts. thanks. and sorry to differ from your point of view if it is.

Comment: I don't seem to know exactly what you want, does this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuFinance or this https://ubuntuguru.wordpress.com/2007/05/25/ubuntu-stock-market-programs/ help you?

Comment: www.tradingview.com has a scripting language and data APIs. I don't know if all markets covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the free open source version of [Chart Geany](https://chartgeany.com/?id=open-source)
They provide Ubuntu packages too.

Comment: You might include a bit more informative output of the programm youre recommending, like i.e. a roundup on the programms features and use the link only as a resource to point to.