# How do I report an Ubuntu Software Center "Listing" problem?

Tags: software-center, security

How do you report a possible security risk to users in Ubuntu Software Center?

There is two game apps in the Ubuntu Software Center called "Karts" and "Kart 1000..."
Both:
- Listed as free
- But the listing is setup to use the "Buy" button, which leads people to purchase through Ubuntu One.
- Dev site link (in that listing) goes to a free generic webpage, which seems like a "front" (false page for phishing).. all the links there go to areas that would not be related in any way to a game vendor. In reality, all links lead to a service to creating webpages and selling extras to do suchwith that service.
- Support link (in that listing) goes to that same page. 
-Licensing is not listed as being something that is a valid Licensing type. Listed as "Proprietary"...

So how to report to whom-- For someone to investigate as a either a "Scam" and possibly get removed. Or...

If they are real products, that are on the level, then the listings need to be corrected, to not be misleading.

We need to protect our users right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple misunderstanding as there are many types of software in the software center. There is Free and Open Source software, that is not only free but licensed under a open source license.

Then there is software available to buy this is usually proprietary but sometimes open source as a developer can make it easier to access by putting a lot of work to get it into the software center and charges for the compiled version of the software.

Then there is proprietary software that was uploaded in the for "purchase" in the software center but the developers chose not to charge for the software aka "Free" as in the cost of money. This however will still list "Buy" and requires a Ubuntu One account, but no monetary transaction takes place.

Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/968974

[Why do I have to 'buy' a free item in the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225895/why-do-i-have-to-buy-a-free-item-in-the-ubuntu-software-center)

But don't worry they aren't scams.